# How to remove value from array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to insert value in if condition and remove it in else condition.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ids=[];
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            var id = $(this).val();
            ids.push(id)
        }
        else
        {
           //remove value from array
        }


    });

});
```

Comment: jQuery is just JavaScript. There is nothing special going on here, except the improper use of a parameter (which does not evaluate to an array). Minimally reproducible with: `"notanarray".push("foo")`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
array.push(id)
```

It should be :

```
ids.push(id)
```

(because your array name is `ids` not `array`)

Answer (score 0):

Click event's callback function parameter is event

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(array){
```

"array" is instance of event on above code.

Then variable "array" cannot have function "push".

Comment: What are you talking about? The OP is not using the event parameter of the handler, so I have no idea what you're getting at. The event object has no `push` method anyway, so this will just cause an error.

Comment: This Question is edited by User. Code is like above on first time